# Initialize multiple distributions using the same seed or same random stream?

Tags: java, random, simulation, colt

I have a Java simulation in which I need to use `Uniform`, `Exponential`, `Poisson`, and `Gamma` distributions - and I need to initialize the random stream and/or each of these distributions with the same seed (so that I can **exactly reproduce** a trajectory *given a fixed seed*).

I am using [Parallel Colt](https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/parallelcolt) (which is a multithreaded version of Colt).

For `Uniform`, I could properly seed a `DoubleUniform` object (after importing from `cern.jet.random.tdouble.DoubleUniform`) as:

```
int fixedSeed = 12345;
doubleUniformDist = new DoubleUniform (0.0, 1.0, fixedSeed);
```

However, for `Exponential`, `Poisson`, and `Gamma` distributions (all in `cern.jet.random.tdouble`), I cannot do the same by passing the `fixedSeed` - because they expect a `DoubleRandomEngine` object to be passed:

> **Constructor Summary**
>
> `Exponential(double lambda, DoubleRandomEngine randomGenerator)`
>   
>   Constructs a Negative Exponential distribution.
>
> `Poisson(double mean, DoubleRandomEngine randomGenerator)`
>   
>   Constructs a poisson distribution.
>
> `Gamma(double alpha, double lambda, DoubleRandomEngine randomGenerator)`
>   
>   Constructs a Gamma distribution.

Is there a way to initialize these (`Exponential`, `Poisson`, and `Gamma`) the same way as I did with `Uniform`? Or should I instantiate a parent/base class (if so, how?) in `cern.jet.random.tdouble` from which all these classes have been extended?

Notes:

1. Again, I'd like to have a single random stream (so that all my
   distributions could use random numbers from that stream) - this is
   very important for reproducibility.
2. An example simulation may need to sample these distributions millions of times (in total) - so performance/speed is always an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `DoubleMersenneTwister`, which extends DoubleRandomEngine, allows you to set a seed in its constructor.

Comment: Yes it does, and so does `MersenneTwister64`. But neither of these seem to have Exponential, Poisson, and Gamma distributions - so no way to seed those using the same seed that I could use to seed a `DoubleMersenneTwister`.

Comment: Er, I believe that you seed the DoubleMersenneTwister with a known seed, and then use _that_ to construct your Exponential, Poisson, and Gamma number generators. Or am I misunderstanding what you need?

Comment: Yes I can seed the `DoubleMersenneTwister` with a known seed, but cannot use that to construct an `Exponential` - because the `Exponential constructor` expects a `RandomEngine` object, and if I pass the `DoubleMersenneTwister`, the `Exponential` seems not to be seeded properly (I get different results with the same seed - which is wrong).

Comment: I think you understood my question perfectly - it's just that I am getting unexpected results doing it this way - so wondering what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Random variate generation of all sorts begins with Uniform(0,1) random numbers.  The last argument in the constructors for `Exponential`, `Poisson`, and `Gamma` is for you to provide a source of Uniform(0,1)'s which extends the `DoubleRandomEngine` abstract class.  It looks like [Parallel Colt provides half a dozen such implementations](http://www.mas.ncl.ac.uk/~ndjw1/share/ParallelColt/doc/cern/jet/random/tdouble/engine/package-summary.html).  You need to pick one of those, create a separate but identically seeded instance for each of the distribution you want to generate, and then construct each your distribution objects with one of the `DoubleRandomEngine` instances you created.  That way the underlying uniform value streams will be identical, and can be suitably transformed into the distributions you want.

Here's a fairly minimalist implementation:

```
import cern.jet.random.tdouble.*;
import cern.jet.random.tdouble.engine.*;

public class RNG {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create two instances of Mersenne Twister, seeded identically
    DoubleRandomEngine twister1 = new DoubleMersenneTwister(42);
    DoubleRandomEngine twister2 = new DoubleMersenneTwister(42);
    // print ten values from each, to show they produce identical U(0,1)'s'
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      System.out.println(twister1.nextDouble() + ", " + twister2.nextDouble());
    }
    System.out.println("\nNow for some exponentials...\n");
    // instantiate two exponentials using our two twisters as the
    // underlying random engine
    Exponential exp1 = new Exponential(3, twister1);
    Exponential exp2 = new Exponential(3, twister2);
    // and print 10 of 'em to show they're synchronized.
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      System.out.println(exp1.nextDouble() + ", " + exp2.nextDouble());
    }
  }
}
```

Since the `Exponential` class transforms the supplied stream of uniforms produced by the "engine" into exponential RVs, and the uniforms are being identically seeded, the exponentials are de facto identically seeded.

Comment: I tried this... picked MersenneTwister64: `MersenneTwister64 myMT = new MersenneTwister64 (seed);` Then created an Exponential as: `Exponential expDist = new Exponential (0.5, myMT)`; Hoping above would create a "separate but identically seeded instance" for the Exponential...

Comment: but then, I cannot reproduce an identical stream of random numbers. My guess is that the last argument in the Exponential constructor expects a RandomEngine object, but I am passing a MersenneTwister64 object

Comment: , which derives from RandomEngine. Not sure how to correctly transform the MersenneTwister64 (myMT) into a RandomEngine object before passing it to the Exponential constructor? Could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: So is there some reason this is not working for you?

Comment: thank you again - I got it fixed. Looks like the varying numbers were due to my use of `staticNextDouble()` methods - which was not right for my purpose, because `staticNextDouble()` uses the rng's internal/default seed, bypassing the seed I was supplying. @pjs

Answer (score 0):

All, thank you - I got it fixed. Looks like the varying numbers I was getting earlier were due to my use of `staticNextDouble()` methods - which was not right for my purpose, because `staticNextDouble()` uses the random number generator's internal/default seed, bypassing the fixed external seed I was supplying.

After replacing the `staticNextDouble()` calls with just `nextDouble()`, I can now exactly reproduce a trajectory given a fixed external seed.